# How to fetch href links of the same class in Nightmare with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, nightmare

I am trying to fetch all `href links` which are inside a separate divs with the  same `class name` using nightmare js... here is my code below....

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var vo = require('vo');

vo(function* () {
    var nightmare = Nightmare();
    var title = yield nightmare
    .goto('https://example.com')
    .type('input[name="q"]', 'search term')
    .click('input[value="some title"]')
    .evaluate(function () {
        //return $('.myclass').find('a').attr('href');
        $('.myclass').find('a').each(function() {
            return $(this).attr('href');
        });

    });
      console.log(title);
    yield nightmare.end();

})(function (err, result) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
});
```

below is my div contents...

```
<div class="myclass"><a href="example1.com">ex1</a>
</div>

<div class="myclass"><a href="example2.com">ex2</a>
</div>

<div class="myclass"><a href="example3.com">ex3</a>
</div>
```

It can fetch one link when i use `return $('.myclass').find('a').attr('href');` but the each function does not work(`returns null`).. any suggestion to fix this issue?

Comment: You want a array of `href's`

Comment: @void yes that's what I am trying to get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know `nightmare.js` but if you want to collect all `href` to an array do it like this:

```
.evaluate(function () {
    var hrefs = [];
    $('.myclass').find('a').each(function() {
        hrefs.push($(this).attr('href'));
    });
    console.log(hrefs);
    //return hrefs
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you only need to use the class name as selector with "a" tag afterward:

```
$(".myClass a").each(function() {
    return $(this).attr("href");
});
```

Here is a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/zero_point/kxxcf8jh/4/)

Comment: @user343681: look at to my updates answer, this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
.evaluate(function () {
    var arr = [];
    $('div.myClass > a').each(function(i) {
      arr.push($(this).prop('href'));
    });
    return arr;
});
```